# Process a string which contains Razor syntext in html and javascripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine, viewengine

If we write the following code directly in a cshtml file:

```
<script>
    var xzz = '@Method1("abc", "test5")';
</script>
```

Then the @Method1 helper functions processes the data and returns a string. The output of the  block is as following:

```
<script>
    var xzz = 'abc test5';
</script>
```

Which is as expected.

But if the *script* block comes from the database (in a property of the model) then can't seem to have the helper method (@Method1) or any Razor syntax processed.
The output is as following (in the view source). Which is not the expected output:

```
<script>
    var xzz = '@Method1("abc", "test5")';
</script>
```

**The expected output should be:**

```
<script>
    var xzz = 'abc test5';
</script>
```

---

I have tried the followings:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Raw(Model.property1).ToString())
```

`Html.RenderPartial("_localizer", Model.property1);` //The _localizer is a cshtml file

```
Html.Raw(Model.property1)

@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Raw(Model.property1).ToString())
```

None of them seems to be working.

Comment: I think you are adding the extra items as part of the rendering. Do they not need to be present before then? I'm not sure how you can do that.

Comment: Just to be sure of what you are asking. You are saying that **@Method1("abc", "test5")** is a string stored in DB and that you want that string to be interpreted as c# code at runtime by the Razor Engine. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe this link might help you https://dzone.com/articles/razor-engine-for-parsing-razor-pages-stored-as-str It handles a problem similar to yours

Comment: @AlfredoA. that is correct. The @Method1("abc", "test5")  is stored as string in the DB with some other razor code and html, script and style block.
I had a look at the dzone sample. That seems to be good for returning content against a virtual view path. Which is not required in this case.